# Do all continuous gauge theories use Lie groups?

Tags: time, gauge-theory, group-theory, diffeomorphism-invariance

The article about [gauge theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_theory) on Wikipedia contains the sentence  "Lie group". How can we prove that the gauge transformations that are given in an article form a Lie group?
I give you an example. Consider [time reparametrisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_constraint). $t$ is replaced by $\tau$ and $x$ by $x'$ with
$$x'(\tau) = x(t)$$ so we have a set of functions $\tau$ acting on $x$. if
they are monotone they have an inverse there is associativity in the composition law, and an identity. So we have a group. But the word Lie does not even appear. How can we prove that this a Lie group?

Comment: Which of the properties of a Lie group do you have difficulty proving?

Comment: One-dimensional Reparametrization is the Lie group ${\rm Diff}[{\mathbb R}]$.

Comment: thank you. i gave the example where t is replaced by tau(t) and x(.) by x(tau(.)). in this case what is(are) the generator(s) of the lie algebra of Diff(R)? how do i exponentiate it to retrieve my x->x'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many mathematical texts (and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group)) often assume that Lie groups are finite-dimensional differential manifolds. [Yang-Mills theories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yang%E2%80%93Mills_theory) and [Chern-Simons theories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chern%E2%80%93Simons_theory) are based on such Lie Groups. However, in physics, gauge theories are sometimes governed by (infinite-dimensional) [Lie](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Lie+groupoid) [groupoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_groupoid). See also [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chern%E2%80%93Simons_theory) related Phys.SE post.

Comment: My problem was that i failed to visualize the tangent vector on the identity  generating a finite diffeomorphisme. Now i see it given by a field of velocities defined ar each point of of the configuration manyfold.